# A relatively large Bluetooth network

Tags: networking, bluetooth

Is it possible and will it be efficient to build a large network of mobile devices over Bluetooth?

For example all Bluetooth enabled devices in a large building so that any device can exchange a small object with any other device in the network through some devices that are in between?

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth is not meant for that. Interference will be a problem if the devices use a high enough TX power level so that all of them can communicate with each other. You can come with a smart application that can forward messages and restrict range of communication to a smaller area, but you'd be reinventing the wheel.

Look into Zigbee or XBee radios instead, this is exactly the scenario they were designed for.